# Getting app:drawableEndCompat instead of android:drawableEnd warning for Lollipop API 21 devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

AS 4.0.1

Use `app:drawableEndCompat instead of android:drawableEnd` warning on API 21 and above

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckStock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_pin_drop
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

The ic_pin_drop is a SVG (Vector Drawable) that was created using `Android Studio File | New | Vector Asset | Configure Vector Assert`

In my `Build.gradle` file I have the following configuration:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
```

As the min is API 21 which is Lollipop I was thinking that vector drawables are supported out of the box and we can use the DrawableEnd, DrawableStart etc without the compat versions?

I was thinking that the compat versions were for pre 21 API level. Kitkat and below. And as I am not targeting that minimum I am not sure why I am getting that warning.

This would result in a cash on those devices less than 21 if the compat version is not used.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The primary motive behind this warning is to make your VectorDrawables look same on all devices by making them backward compatible.
By using "Compat", you would be ensuring that using your vector asset would not crash your app for devices below API 21(Lollipop). In short, using `drawableEndCompat` would allow anyone to use the same features of `drawableEnd` on older APIs(<21).
Now you would be thinking that what should I choose:
If you are using `drawableEndCompat`, it would work as you expect in every device. Devices with API more than 21 would internally unwrap them as normal `drawableEnd` as far as I know.
If you choose to use `drawableEnd`, it will be working for API 21 and above only.

If you think that I don't need any Compat Support : You may increase your application's minimum SDK from current value to atleast 21. Then you can use keyword `drawableEnd` peacefully without any warning.
Also, you may opt to create different layout file for different APIs under which in layout file for below API 21, use `drawableEndCompat` and for API 21 and above use `drawableEnd`. In my opinion, you can also check whether you can use both attributes at same place. I feel like that they can work together as well.

If you are not supporting devices below API 21, there is no problem: You should have no issues/warning. Also, one more thing I need to tell you - Android Studio sometimes throw warnings or bugs; even if you are right. In that case, if you feel that you were correct, you should try invalidate/restart option after clicking File option in Menu Bar. I would also suggest to try restarting your system to everyone who are using system for long durations or always keeping it on sleep mode.

So, for a `TextView`, you should use `app:drawableEndCompat` (or start, top, bottom) instead of `app:drawableEnd`

Answer (score 4):

Vector drawables are supported since API 21 but new features are added over time, even to vector drawables. It may be a good idea to use AppCompat and not worry about that.

Tinting *compound drawables* on `TextView`s was added [in API 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawableTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)). The suggestion is pushing you towards the compat variant, where the feature is backported.

- `app:drawable*Compat`
- `app:drawableTint` and `app:drawableTintMode`

If you don't use compound drawable tinting you may be fine with the platform version of the attributes.

- `android:drawable*`
- `android:drawableTint` and `android:drawableTintMode` (added in API 23)

Comment: Even though I am not using any `drawableTint` or `drawableTintMode` in my TextView. I will still get that warning? I can understand that the warning might appear if I was trying to use a drawableTint on a device that was less than 23.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, the main idea is actually this: You're using AppCompat, it pushes you towards AppCompat attributes, otherwise you might get unexpected behavior. Similar to `colorPrimary` vs. `android:colorPrimary` and so on.